# Toggling a Bootstrap nav dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've created a Bootstrap menu like in the snippet with a lightbox effect over the rest of the page content when it expands.

I added the first functions in JS to try hide/display the `lightbox_container` element when the nav is toggled.

The second function then was to try toggle the nav again when they click off of the nav on the `lightbox_container` element but this doesn't work properly as it will add `style="display:none"` to the dropdown so when you try expand it again it doesn't display.

```js
$("#navbarSupportedContent").on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
  if (e.type == 'hide') {
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
  } else if (e.type == 'show') {
    lightbox.style.display = "block";
  }
});

$("#lightbox_container").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#navbarSupportedContent").hasClass("show")) {
    $("#navbarSupportedContent").hide();
  }
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
  lightbox.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#lightbox_container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 40;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

nav {
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: red;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store">All Products&nbsp;›</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading 1 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading 2 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading 3 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="lightbox_container"></div>
```

Comment: Just a side note - if you use jquery, there is no need to use `document.getElementById`, use `$(...)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$("#navbarSupportedContent").hide();` you should just remove the `show` class, like:

`$("#navbarSupportedContent").removeClass("show");`

See the snippet:

```js
$("#navbarSupportedContent").on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
  if(e.type == 'hide'){
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
  }else if(e.type == 'show'){
   lightbox.style.display = "block";
  }
});
$("#lightbox_container").on("click", function(){
  if($("#navbarSupportedContent").hasClass("show")){
    $("#navbarSupportedContent").removeClass("show");
  }
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
  lightbox.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#lightbox_container{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:40;
  display:none;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
nav{
  z-index:50;
  background-color:red;
}
.icon{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}

body { height: 2000px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store">All Products&nbsp;›</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading 1 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading 2 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading 3 ›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="1">1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="2">2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="3">3</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>        
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="lightbox_container"></div>
```